# Show that no sequence in $E=\{\chi_A : A \subset \Bbb R \text{ discrete}\}$ will converge to $\chi_{\Bbb R}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

> Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$ and each $\{0,1\}$ discrete. We can express $X$ as characteristic functions as follows $X=\{\chi_A \mid A \subset \Bbb R\}$. Show that no sequence in $E=\{\chi_A : A  \subset \Bbb R \text{ discrete}\}$ will converge to $\chi_{\Bbb R}$.

Let $x_n \in E$, then $x_n=(\chi_{A_1}, \chi_{A_2}, \dots)$. Assume that $x_n$ did converge to $\chi_{\Bbb R}$, this means that for each $i$ the sequence $\chi_{A_i} \to \chi_{\Bbb R}$.

So there exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that for $n > n_0$ : $\chi_{A_n} \in U$ for any open nbhd $U$ of $\chi_{\Bbb R}$.

Hints on how to get a contradiction here? I tried to think about the discreteness of $\Bbb R$, but we can equip $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology and then $\chi_{\Bbb R} \in E$?

Comment: No to the last paragraph: the topology on the reals is mean t to be the standard one and you cannot change it.

Comment: In fact $\chi_{\Bbb R}$ is in the closure of $N:=\{\chi_E: E \subseteq \Bbb R \text{ finite }\}$ but not in the closure of any subset of $N$ of size less than $\mathfrak{c}$. Technically, the tightness of $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$ is $\mathfrak{c}=|\Bbb R|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the convergence it follows that $\Bbb R = \bigcup_n A_n$ and this is impossible by cardinality reasons. (If $x \in \Bbb R$ then $\pi_x^{-1}[\{1\}$ is a neighbourhood of $\chi_{\Bbb R}$ and so contains some $\chi_{A_n}$ which implies that $x \in A_n$ etc. )

Comment: Why does this follow from convergence? Does $x_n \to \chi_{\Bbb R}$ imply that after some $n_0$ the sequence is constant $\chi_{\Bbb R}$?

Comment: @Ylvas:  Fix $x\in \mathbb{R}$.  Use the convergence of the sequence $\chi_{A_n}(x)\rightarrow 1$ together with the fact that the output of any $\chi_{A_n}$ is in $\{0,1\}$ to show that $x$ must be in some $A_n$.  (In fact, $x$ must be in all but finitely many $A_n$.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito Why would $\chi_{A_n}(x)\rightarrow 1$? For $n$ large enough shouldn't there be a point $x_0$ for which $\chi_{A_n}(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: @Ylvas:  Because $\chi_{A_n}\rightarrow \chi_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\chi_{\mathbb{R}}(x) = 1$.  (It's been a long time since I thought about sequences of functions, so I apologize if I'm making a stupid mistake...)

Comment: Gotcha! Under the assumption it converges. I don't quite still understand how does this imply that even if $\Bbb R = \bigcup_n A_n$ how is this impossible due to cardinality as Henno points out. $\bigcup_n A_n$ could be a cover for $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Ylvas all $A_n$ are discrete and hence at most countable.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but how can discreteness imply countability? We can put the discrete topology on any space it shouldn't matter if the space is countable or uncountable.

Comment: @Ylvas any subspace of the reals is separable. A separable discrete subspace is at most countable. The $A_n$ inherit the subspace topology of the usual topology.